# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions Error msg 1033

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery

What's wrong with this query? Also I've tried to use (select top 100 percent) it works but not effective.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[viewTblDaily] 
AS 
   SELECT
       tblTasks.TaskID,TUsers.UserFirstName + ' ' + TUsers.UserLastName AS [UserFullName],
       TTasksType.TaskDescription AS TaskType,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR, tblTasks.DateTask, 103) DateTask,
       tblTasks.TimeTask,
       tblTasks.TaskDescription,
       tblTasks.statusTask,
       TUsers.UserID AS [userID]
   FROM 
       tblTasks
   LEFT JOIN 
       tblTaskType AS TTasksType ON tblTasks.TaskTypeID = TTasksType.TaskID
   LEFT JOIN 
       tblUsers AS TUsers ON TUsers.UserID = tblTasks.UserID
   WHERE 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tblTasks.DateTask, 102) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 102) 
       AND tblTasks.StatusTask = 0  
   ORDER BY
       TaskID
```

Comment: As the error clearly says: you **cannot** have an `ORDER BY` in a view definition. Scrap that and it'll work just fine. Whoever selects from this view will have to provide the `ORDER BY` if they need it

Comment: Just a note, that's not the best way do do a search for one day since SQL server will not use any indexes for DateTask if you convert it to char. To work better you should use DateTask >= xxx and DateTask < yyy where you calculate the start of current day from getdate and then the next day for the upper limit.

Comment: as marc_s said, do you really need an order by clause in this case? If you want a deterministic results you can add the order-by clause to the select  where the view is used.

Comment: yes, taskID its just for example, i need this method for DateTask and TimeTask for Monthly view.

Answer (score 0):

a view is not an actual table in DB. (in fact MySQL DB will not like an ordered table definition either)
it exists only as a schema waiting for you to use it.
ordering is not relevant

Comment: This isn't a MySQL question...

Comment: I think the point Zahiro Mor was trying to make is that ANSI compliant DBMS systems do not honor/allow ORDER BY in views, and called out MySQL as another example.

Comment: I stand corrected - this is not a MySQL question. thanks Dan for explaining :). 
my point was - order is irrelevant when you talk about a table/view definitions. it is only relevant when pulling data out to console. there are workarounds of course but the above point is methodically valid

Comment: TaskID variable its for example, I need this method for TimeTask and DateTask.

Comment: do you mean something like ranking functions?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Comment: no, just order by DateTask and TimeTask. without ranking.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you this

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[viewTblDaily] 
AS 
   SELECT
       tblTasks.TaskID,TUsers.UserFirstName + ' ' + TUsers.UserLastName AS [UserFullName],
       TTasksType.TaskDescription AS TaskType,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR, tblTasks.DateTask, 103) DateTask,
       tblTasks.TimeTask,
       tblTasks.TaskDescription,
       tblTasks.statusTask,
       TUsers.UserID AS [userID],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TaskID) As RowNum
   FROM 
       tblTasks
   LEFT JOIN 
       tblTaskType AS TTasksType ON tblTasks.TaskTypeID = TTasksType.TaskID
   LEFT JOIN 
       tblUsers AS TUsers ON TUsers.UserID = tblTasks.UserID
   WHERE 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tblTasks.DateTask, 102) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 102) 
       AND tblTasks.StatusTask = 0
```

And you will see its result will be ordered by that `RowNum` or to guarantee order of your result after select you can also use `RowNum`.

Comment: It's true that the result is most likely always in the order of row_number if only one exists in the select, but at least I wouldn't recommend using this. Just add the order by where it belongs, to the select clause where the view is used.

Comment: @JamesZ I'm agree with you ;).

Comment: @shA.t, you might refactor the date comparision expression in the `WHERE` clause such that the expression is sargable like JamesZ suggested, allowing an index on `DateTask` to be used: `CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, getdate()) AS date) AND tblTasks.DateTask < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, getdate()) AS date)`

Comment: Thank you very much the solution is work, but you forget to specify the table name in the Order By. (tblTasks.TaskID).